# Change whole application theme based on a state React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create an application which user can change primary color and for that I've created this class

```
const mode = true;

export default class Colors {
    static primary() {
        return mode ? '#fff' : '#000';
    }

    static accent() {
        return mode ? '#fff' : '#000';
    }
}
```

and in Components

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary()
    }
});
```

so when user clicks on changing the theme the mode will change. The problem is how can I force all Components and Pages to refresh and use the new styles when the `mode` changes?

Comment: Use Redux State and use throughout the application to change the style.

Comment: https://medium.com/@mosesesan/tutorial-react-native-redux-boilerplate-4899f5c4f431 you can check this to understand redux.  Or you can use any state management plugin to achieve this requirement.

Comment: You might want to check [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced) library to componentize your styles, including the feature to implement [themeProvider](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read This:

https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053

then you can access state on any Screen of page via mapStateToProp.

But if you want to store to store theme permanently then you have to store in userDefault

```
    import React , {PureComponent} from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      } from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

    const mapStateToProps = (() => {
      return {
        colorStyle: colorTheme.style,
      };
    });

    class ColorTheme extends PureComponent {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      render() {
          console.log(this.props.colorStyle)
      }

    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ColorTheme);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you like using global variables or not. But they can really help you here, you don't need a state. Just create some global variables in your index.js such as

```
global.themeColorDark = "rgb(0,106,176)";
global.themeColorLight = "rgb(10,143,192)";
global.themeColorBackground = "white";
```

and then, you can access and edit these variables from anywhere in your app. without importing any file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux(or something like that)

- Define a variable in reducer
- Bind mapStateToProps function to component
- Then change that variable in reducer when you want